# Infinite product expression of partition function

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I'm working on a problem (specifically, I'm using an exam paper without course notes to prepare for a course starting in September),

> Define the partition function $P(q)$ and give its infinite product expression.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Generating_function) has

> The generating function for $p(n)$ is given by
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1-x^k}\right)$$

But how does this allow us to evalute $p(n)$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x^k} = 1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k}+\cdots$.  As an example, to find the number of partitions of $0,1,2,3,4$, expand $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)(1+x^3+\cdots)(1+x^4+\cdots)(1+\cdots)$ to get $1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+\cdots$ so the answers are $1,1,2,3,5$ respectively

Comment: @Henry But we want to find a function of $n$ and now we're working with only $x$? And when I put $x=0$ into $1+x+2x^2+\dots$ I get $1$ (as expected), but when I put $x=1$ in it diverges. What am I missing?

Comment: When you put $x=1$ into $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n$ you get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)$ which counts every partition of every natural number... it is $\infty$, as it ought to be.

Comment: @BrianMoehring OK; so, back to my original question: how does this allow us to evaluate $p(n)$ for a particular $n$?

Comment: Look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series whose first several terms were given by Henry.  The generating function doesn't necessarily give a useful formula for the sequence it's a generating function of, but it contains all the information necessary for $p(n)$ in it, so it often allows us to solve further problems.

Comment: Formal way: take the $n$th derivative of the sum or product at $x=0$ and divide that by $n!$; clearly with the  sum that gives $p(n)$, and doing it to the product gives the numerical value.   Easy method: look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion.

Comment: @Henry I think that's what I was looking for. Your comments are enough for me, but if you care to write them up as an answer for the site, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comments as requested:*

$\frac{1}{1-x^k} = 1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k}+\cdots$.

As an example, to find the number of partitions of $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$, expand $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)(1+x^3+\cdots)(1+x^4+\cdots)(1+\cdots)$ to get $1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+\cdots$ so the answers are $1$, $1$, $2$, $3$, and $5$ respectively.

- The formal way to use generating functions: take the $n$th derivative of the sum or product at $x=0$ and divide that by $n!$; clearly with the sum that gives $p(n)$, and doing it to the product gives the numerical value.
- Easy method: look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion.